# When a neutron star accretes matter, will its mass increase?

Tags: neutron-star, accretion-discs

When a nova gets matter, the outcome is that it may lose more matter because of eruptions. Only some kind of nova's masses can increase stably.

A white dwarf may become a supernova after it exceeds the Chandrasekhar limit, and we study that much. A neutron star can get mass too, why do not we talk about their end much?

How about a neutron star when it gets matter from accretion? It is necessary that its mass will increase? 
When will it collapse?

Comment: by "Nova gets matter", do you mean a white dwarf, where, as it adds mass, usually from a near-by star, it can reach the Chandrasekhar limit?   As a Neutron star adds mass it continues to get more dense and there is a point where it likely turns into a black hole.    I don't think the event has ever been observed though.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit   I suspect it's a smaller explosion than the white dwarf cause there's no influx of fusion energy.

Comment: kind of related.  The 2nd comment explains what happens to matter as it falls into a Neutron Star.   http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/what-would-happen-if-a-body-were-to-fall-into-a-neutron-star

Answer (score 2):

The neutron stars have about 1.1 to 3 solar masses. If the neutron star accretes mass, its mass will increase and once it crosses the [Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit), the star will collapse to form a black hole.

On way of this happening is in the case where one of the binary stars becomes a neutron star as in [X-ray pulsars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_pulsar). The neutron star receives gas supply from its companion, which increases its mass,for example [CenX3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurus_X-3).

[image: Swift J1749]

Source: nasa.gov

Though this method could lead tothe formation of black hole, no observational evidence exists as of today.

Answer (score -1):

A nova is generally understood as an explosion of a star.  Thus comparing a nova to a stable neutron star is kind of a nonsensical thing to do.

If you're asking if a star goes nova and the core that remains is a neutron star after the resulting explosion, will it's mass increase overall?  The answer is no, since it loses a lot of mass in the process of going nova.  However, it is now more dense than before and the concentration of matter is in a much smaller space (the neutron star).  (The explosion compresses part of the star and pushes the rest of it outward off into space).

If you're asking if a neutron star's mass will increase if you throw matter at it, the answer is yes.  Just like any other form of matter.  Is there a limit to how bit you can increase it?  No; however, past a certain density it will compress into a black hole (which do not have a size limit as far as we know).

You may want to edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: A Nova is not the explosion of a star, it is an explosion *on* a star.

Comment: @Rob Jefferies Thanks, you'r right I'm treating it like a supernova.  I'll edit my answer later.